# Spark Sql appears to be consuming the RDD when writing to postgres

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataset I'm writing to postgres using an implementation of ForeachPartitionFunction. My understanding of spark is that every call on the builder syntax creates a new dataset object, so conceivably. It seems like writing to postgres is flushing the dataset or something, or there is some kind of caching issue that I'm not aware of.

In the second call to dataset2.show() I'm expecting to still see data in the dataset, but instead dataset is empty.

```
var dataset1 = spark.read()
        .format("jdbc")
        .option("driver", "org.postgresql.Driver")
        .option("query", sourceQuery)
        .load()

// some transformation steps

dataset1.show()

var dataset2 = dataset1
        .drop(col("language"))
        .distinct()
        .withColumn("language", lit("NoneSelected"))

dataset2.show()

//PostgresWriter is my implementation of ForeachPartitionFunction and is mainly here to do upserts
dataset1.foreachPartition(new PostgresWriter())

dataset2.show()
```

Comment: dataset1.cache()
dataset1.foreachPartition(new PostgresWriter())